# Use of Parcelable to pass a list through an intent put parameters

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've a List of a Class I've made, Card, and I need to pass it to another activity through an intent.

I'm trying to implement Parcelable as somebody suggested me.

The fact is this List contains objects which are mode of other classes which extend the Card one.

So for instance I have this Guard class which extends Card, but when I run the app I get this error:

> Error:(10, 19) error: constructor Card in class Card cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: Parcel
>   found: no arguments
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

The Card class is the following:

```
public class Card implements Parcelable{
private String mName;

protected Card(Parcel in) {
    mName = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<Card> CREATOR = new Creator<Card>() {
    @Override
    public Card createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Card(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Card[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Card[size];
    }
};



public String getName(){
    return mName;
}
public void setName(String name){
    mName = name;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mName);
}
```

}

I have **implemented** two methods which Android Studio told me to add, and I let it add them by itself, they are `describeContents()` and `writeToParcel()`
but as you saw I get this other error in all the other (6 in total) classes that `extend` `Card` (and **are contained** in the `List` I need to pass via n intent)

This instead is the Guard class (the other 5 are all the same)

```
public class Guard extends Card {

public Guard(){
    this.setName("Guard");
}
```

}

What do you think is the **problem**? How should I **solve** this and **why**?

This is how I managed to **create** the `intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RandomAssignment.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("CHARACTERS", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) characters);
startActivity(intent);
```

and how to **retrieve** it:

```
characters = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("CHARACTERS");
```

Comment: Where are you seeing that error? You will probably need another constructor which doesn't take a Parcel as a parameter

Comment: I'm seeing it when I run the app, the problem is in the Guard (and the 5 others) class.. I don't understand how should I make this other constructor @fractalwrench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as of Doc

> ArrayList
>   public class ArrayList 
>   extends AbstractList implements Cloneable, Serializable, RandomAccess

its clear ArrayList is not parcelable.

Create CustomClass Extending ArrayList with Parcelable implemented.
Then Use it in Intent as `putParcelableArrayListExtra`

One more option you have `Serializable`, just add marker to `ArrayListItems`

Comment: Mmm you think Parcelable is the way or not? If yes, how shoud I do what you said? Kinda new to Android

Comment: @Snip3r_bow Yes . you got right. . Parcelable is best way. Since parcelable has some optimisation in android for performance. Serialization is kinda easy go.

Comment: So why am I getting those errors with Parcelable? Is it the best way but not for ArrayLists?

Comment: since arraylist is not parcelable its not allowing you to put in intent as "putParcelableArrayListExtra". And as of serializable its just marker interface, no need any implementation if don't need to.As i said its easy go

Comment: So should I remove that Parcelable implementation in the Card class? And put serializable instead?

Comment: Good.. Its just way that u can choose to implement.. Can please up vote if your question is been answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your class Parcelable containing object of another class , you need to make that class Parcelable first .

To put list of your parcelable class

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
i.putParcelableArrayList("YOUR_KEY", new ArrayList<ParcelableClass>(Arraylistobject));
```

To retrieve the list

```
ArrayList<ParcelableClass> testing = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Your_KEY");
```

You should definitely read about Parcelable first from Official doc and from here  https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable